# Word for -> “This is amazing!” + “I’m a moron. How did I not see this before?”

Tags: single-word-requests

Good word for this feeling?

The delight and frustration of discovering something incredible hiding in plain sight

“This is amazing!” + “I’m a moron. How did I not see this before?”

Comment: With great sarcasm, my European grandmother used to say "Good Morning!" in a tone like *You just woke up to this now, you effing fool?*, except that as a rabbi's wife, she did not curse. But it was a curse. Today, it's wake up and smell the coffee.

Comment: It depends on the context. In British English, it could be "Well, Hello! [What have we here!]"

Comment: "I must have been blind!"

Comment: “Duh” is a response to another person’s insight. To your own—faceplant?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of no single word that means *exactly* that, but a now popularized expression is [**d'oh**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/d'oh).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   —used to express sudden recognition of a foolish blunder or an ironic turn of events

Although it's somewhat lacking in the "this is amazing" sense, it's more than sufficient in the "I'm a moron" sense.

Generally speaking, it can be used after doing something stupid without the intended result, and then watching something *else* do something much more intelligent and producing exactly what was intended.

It can also be used to express your own stupidity for not noticing something right in front of your eyes. For instance, spending 5 minutes hunting for your glasses only to discover that you've actually been wearing them all along. You're happy to discover where they are, but annoyed with yourself at the same time.